# Update a MySQL row after a set time in PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rows

Alright, so say you have 5 rows in a table. I want to know how you could change a row when someone sent a request. So, if I input something into a PHP form, it would use information in the first row, and then disable it for the time that I specified. And then when someone else wanted to use the form, it would use the second row, access the information for a set time, and then disable. So on, and so on. After the time, it should reset the row back to its original status and be ready for use. I am so sorry if I didn't explain this well, or it didn't make any sense. I am not advanced in the slightest on the subject. Thanks anyone for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an algorithmic issue.

You could save PHP Session ID and expiration time in a row of the table (use php function session_id() ). For new users, use rows with blank or expired Session ID. In the case of expired row, you should "renew" it (reset values entered by previous user).

Comment: Well, I expect many users to be using this process, and I would need it to be almost instant after the time is up for another user.

Comment: Is there a way to make a seperate attribute that holds a 0 or a 1, and then when the time is up, it sets the value to 0, making it usable. That way you can search by that id. I am just not sure how to make it to where the attribute is modified for a specified time.

Comment: If you remember expiration time in a row, then you could select these rows by using
      SELECT * FROM ... WHERE NOW() > exptime

Comment: I get the concept, but I am honestly not sure how to apply it.

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks for the help edtech